How to supply a Jacobian to the nlsLM() function in R?
I'm working on non-linear modeling using the minpack.lm package, specifically with the nlsLM() function. I want to supply a custom Jacobian to improve the model's performance, but I keep encountering the following error when trying to include it:
Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~N + TT, jac = fcn.jac) :
invalid type (closure) for variable '(jac)'

I am using nlsLM() because I need to generate a model object for later use in making predictions. Below is a slightly modified version of an example from the documentation.
Question: How can I correctly supply a Jacobian to the nlsLM() function? What am I doing wrong?
library(minpack.lm)

# Values over which to simulate data
x <- seq(0,5, length = 100)

# Model based on a list of parameters
getPred <- function(parS, xx) parS$a * exp(xx * parS$b) + parS$c

# Parameter values used to simulate data
pp <- list(a = 9, b = -1, c = 6)

# Simulated data with noise
simDNoisy <- getPred(pp, x) + rnorm(length(x), sd = .1)

# Fit the model using nlsLM
mod <- nlsLM(simDNoisy ~ a * exp(b * x) + c,
             start = c(a = 3, b = -0.001, c = 1),
             trace = TRUE)

# Plot data
plot(x, simDNoisy, main = "data")

# Plot fitted values
lines(x, fitted(mod), col = 2, lwd = 2)

# Now let's introduce another example using a custom Jacobian

# Create a declining cosine function with noise
TT <- seq(0, 8, length = 501)
tau <- 2.2
N0 <- 1000
a <- 0.25
f0 <- 8
Ndet <- N0 * exp(-TT/tau) * (1 + a * cos(f0 * TT))
N <- Ndet + rnorm(length(Ndet), mean = Ndet, sd = .01 * max(Ndet))

# Function to simulate data
f <- function(TT, tau, N0, a, f0) {
  expr <- expression(N0 * exp(-TT/tau) * (1 + a * cos(f0 * TT)))
  eval(expr)
}

# Analytical gradient (Jacobian)
j <- function(TT, tau, N0, a, f0) {
  expr <- expression(N0 * exp(-TT/tau) * (1 + a * cos(f0 * TT)))
  c(eval(D(expr, "tau")), eval(D(expr, "N0")),
    eval(D(expr, "a")), eval(D(expr, "f0")))
}

# Define a residual function
fcn <- function(p, TT, N, fcall, jcall) {
  N - do.call("fcall", c(list(TT = TT), as.list(p)))
}

# Define the analytical Jacobian
fcn.jac <- function(p, TT, N, fcall, jcall) {
  -do.call("j", c(list(TT = TT), as.list(p)))
}

# Attempt to fit the model with the custom Jacobian
mod <- nlsLM(N ~ N0 * exp(-TT/tau) * (1 + a * cos(f0 * TT)),
             start = c(tau = 2.2, N0 = 1500, a = 0.25, f0 = 10),
             trace = TRUE, jac = fcn.jac)


Whenever I try to pass the Jacobian (fcn.jac) into nlsLM(), it results in an error. Any insights into the correct way to supply the Jacobian to the nlsLM() function would be greatly appreciated!

This works fine without the jacobian.  If you must use an analytic jacobian it would be easier to use nlsr::nlxb which will calculate the symbolic jacobian for you.
